# Which ~ effect on vs influenced by ~

Tags: usage

Can I use which ~ effect on, instead of using influenced by ~?

For example:

1. People's lifestyles are based on individual choices, influenced by personal interests and social interactions.
2. People's lifestyles are based on individual choices, which personal interests and social interactions effect on.

Do you think those 2 mean the same or is it not right to use the word 'effect' like this?

Comment: The second one is wrong.  You can ask basic questions like this on the excellent English Learning site, go for it !

Answer (score 1):

> is it not right to use the word 'effect' like this?

*Effect* is used incorrectly.

As a "rule of thumb": *effect* is not often used as a verb, versus *affect*.   Unless you're using somewhat common phrases such as *X effects change in Y* you are probably using *effect* incorrectly, meant to use *affect*, or simply don't need to use it.  *Effect(s)(ed)(ing) X on Y* is even rarer as a set of words used together.

You might have meant this in the second sentence:

> People's lifestyles are based on individual choices, *affected by* which personal interests and social interactions.

*To influence X* is means to try to change X's choices, typically for someone's benefit.  X has to be something that can make a decision, like a person.

*To affect X* means to change something about X.  This could be thoughts, choices, or physical attributes.  For example - *The earthquake affected the house's foundation*.
There is also not the underlying assumption with *affect* you want to change things for the benefit of something, you may simply be expressing a consequence of an event or other action.

*To effect X* means to do something to bring about the change named X.  X is typically not a person or anything except some sort of desired result.

Answer (score 0):

In order for sentence number two to mean the same as sentence number one, you could say "have an effect on", or "on which personal interests and social interactions  have an effect". Saying "effect on" is incorrect usage of the word, but you could also say "affect" instead. Most of the time affect is a verb, and effect is a noun, except in some cases.